# How do use urllib.request.urlopen() with add_hotkey()?

Tags: python, urllib

`add_hotkey(random_macro_list[i], lambda: request.urlopen, args=(choice(RANDOM_LIST)))`

I run this line of code, but every time a hotkey is pressed these errors are sparked:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan Van-Doninck\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan Van-Doninck\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan Van-Doninck\Desktop\Programing\Programs\totallynotavirus\venv\lib\site-packages\keyboard\_generic.py", line 58, in process
    if self.pre_process_event(event):
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan Van-Doninck\Desktop\Programing\Programs\totallynotavirus\venv\lib\site-packages\keyboard\__init__.py", line 218, in pre_process_event
    callback(event)
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan Van-Doninck\Desktop\Programing\Programs\totallynotavirus\venv\lib\site-packages\keyboard\__init__.py", line 649, in <lambda>
    handler = lambda e: (event_type == KEY_DOWN and e.event_type == KEY_UP and e.scan_code in _logically_pressed_keys) or (event_type == e.event_type and callback())
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan Van-Doninck\Desktop\Programing\Programs\totallynotavirus\venv\lib\site-packages\keyboard\__init__.py", line 637, in <lambda>
    callback = lambda callback=callback: callback(*args)
TypeError: <lambda>() takes 0 positional arguments but 43 were given
```

anybody knows what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You provide `args=(choice(RANDOM_LIST))` so `keyboard` tries to call your lambda with these arguments. Also using brackets is not enough to create a tuple, in that case it gets string which probably is of length 43 and tries to pass every character as a different argument. And I don't see a call to urlopen anywhere.

You probably wanted to write something like this:

`add_hotkey(random_macro_list[i], lambda url: request.urlopen(url), args=(choice(RANDOM_LIST),))`

Note the comma.